# Return multiple query results into a single data set

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sql-server-2016

I currently have a powershell process that builds a query string, creates a data table, creates a sql connection, creates a sql command, creates a data reader, and loads the results from the sql command into the data table.  I then pass that data table to sql server as a user defined table type.  It looks something like this:

```
$Query =
    "
    SELECT 
        group_id AS GroupID,
        listener_id AS ListenerID,
        dns_name AS DNSName,
        [Port],
        is_conformant AS IsConformant,
        ip_configuration_string_from_cluster AS IPConfigurationString
    FROM master.sys.availability_group_listeners
    "

    #where we're storing query results
    $Datatable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable


    $sqlConnection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=ServerName; Database=Audit;Trusted_Connection=True;Connect Timeout=5;"
    $sqlConnection.Open()


    $sqlCommand = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $sqlCommand.Connection = $sqlConnection
    $sqlCommand.CommandText = $Query
    $sqlCommand.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::Text
    $sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 5


    $DataReader = $sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
    $Datatable.Load($DataReader)


    if ($Datatable.Rows.Count -gt 0)
    {
        Write-Host "        Insert Results"


        $sqlConnection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        $sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server='servername; Database=Audit;Trusted_Connection=True;"
        $sqlConnection.Open()


        $sqlCommand = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        $sqlCommand.Connection = $sqlConnection
        $sqlCommand.CommandText = "InsertResults"
        $sqlCommand.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure
        $sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 10
        $sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@results", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Structured).value = $datatable


        $sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()                     
        $sqlConnection.Close()    
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "        No Results"
    }
```

What I would like to do is modify that query string to where it will return multiple results, ie it will have multiple select statements, and put those results into multiple data tables, and then pass those individual data tables to sql server.  I know powershell has a data set object, but I'm unsure how you would populate it.

Is this possible?  How would one do this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it is possible.  You just have to use a SQL Adapter instead.

```
$Query =
"
SELECT 
    group_id AS GroupID,
    listener_id AS ListenerID
FROM master.sys.availability_group_listeners

SELECT 
    g.group_id AS GroupID,
    CAST(g.name AS VARCHAR(255)) AS AGName
FROM master.sys.availability_groups g
"


$sqlConnection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=servername; Database=master;Trusted_Connection=True;Connect Timeout=5;"
$sqlConnection.Open()


$sqlCommand = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$sqlCommand.Connection = $sqlConnection
$sqlCommand.CommandText = $Query
$sqlCommand.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::Text
$sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 5


$Dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$sqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$sqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $sqlCommand

[void]$sqlAdapter.Fill($Dataset)


$sqlConnection.Close()


Write-Host $Dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0].data

$dt1 = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$dt2 = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$dt1 = $Dataset.Tables[0]
$dt2 = $Dataset.Tables[1]

foreach($row in $dt1)
{
    Write-Host $row.GroupID $row.ListenerID
}


foreach($row in $dt2)
{
    Write-Host $row.GroupID $row.AGName
}
```